# Debugging Blazor WASM in VS Code fails because of Unbound breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor, blazor-webassembly, vscode-debugger

I have just created a new Blazor WASM and I have followed the below resource to enable debugging in VS Code

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code

And as per it, I put a breakpoint on the currentCount++ line, but on debugging it does not hit because the breakpoint is unbound.

[image: VS Code in debug mode]

The dotnet version is 6

Launch Settings:

"profiles": {
"TestVSCodeDebug": {
"commandName": "Project",
"dotnetRunMessages": true,
"launchBrowser": true,
"inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7240;http://localhost:5053",
"environmentVariables": {
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
}
}
}

Launch.json :

"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
"type": "blazorwasm",
"name": "Launch and Debug BlazorWASM",
"request": "launch",
"url": "https://localhost:7240"

```
    }
]
```

Above is orginal.Below updated on 24th-Jan-2022:

The breakpoint hits in VS 2022 Preview

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem. I found a workaround, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72037574) for working config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This workaround got VSCode breakpoints to hit for me

1. Changing my **launch.json** to :

   ```
   {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
      {
           "name": ".NET Core Debug Blazor Web Assembly in Chrome",
           "type": "blazorwasm",
           "request": "launch",
           "timeout": 30000,
           "url": "http://localhost:5000",
           "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
           "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
      }]
   }
   ```
2. Also make sure you're launching with **http** and not https.
3. Install and debug with chrome :( Can't get it to work on FF.

More info here :
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20597